# What Visual Studio 2008 version to download for x86 .NET development?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, 64-bit

What version should I download? I only see VS 2008 x86 and some "WOW64" stuff on MSDN. Will "Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition (x86)" work?

Answer (score 4):

Yes VS2008 x86 will work on both x86 and x64.  There is no x64 only version.

WOW64 refers to windows32 on windows64 and it is a transparent emulation laywer that allows x86 programs to run on x64 operating systems.  WOW64 will automatically be used if you run an x86 Windows program on an x64 Windows operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should work. Any reasons why you think it wont? Are you running a 32 bit or 64bit os?

Comment: I am runnib x86 version on Win 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify a bit, there is only one version of Visual Studio with respect to processor architecture: x86.  Visual Studio does not run natively on 64 bit operating systems but instead uses the Wow64 environment to run as an x86 application.

In short, don't focus on the x86 portion when downloading Visual Studio :)