# what to look out for when migrating .net apps to Windows 7, 64 bit

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, 64-bit

we are migrating our desktop to windows 7, 64 bit (from 32bit Windows XP).  We have a number of Winforms C# applications and are trying to figure out what to look out for in this upgrade.  Is there any suggestions or good resources to look at from a developer point of view on what to look out for to make this a smooth transition?

Comment: 32-bit apps has no problem on running 64-bit OS

Comment: possible duplicate of [64 bits stuff for C# development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889941/64-bits-stuff-for-c-development)

Comment: @Adeel: There are some differences in where the os places files and the registry is changed. Also, the question is about Win7 64Bit versus XP 32Bit, so there are some differences worth noting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.Net behaves more or less the same on 32Bit and 64Bit OS'es, so there is not much to worry about there AFAIK.

The main things you must be aware of are changes in the OS itself:

- The registry is changed, so if you read or write registry settings you may have to modify that code
- Some file locations are changed. You have Program Files for 64-bit apps and Program Files (x86) for 32-bit apps for instance. Also some other system folders have moved.
- UAC may cause trouble. You must test for this
- Your program may not have rights to write to some locations on the file system or in the registry. You may have to ask the user for permission or even require the user to run the application as an Administrator in the worst case.

Those are the changes I can think of at the moment. In most cases your app will run just fine on both OS'es.

Answer (score 2):

If your app pokes around in the OS portions of the Windows registry or in the Windows system directory or program files directory, you may run into issues when running your 32 bit app on a 64 bit Windows OS.

The vast majority of applications don't muck around in these core system areas and run just fine in a 64 bit Win OS.

Comment: You'll also run into issues if you try to do this on a 32-bit version of the OS. UAC in Windows Vista/7 just doesn't allow you the same ability to muck about in the system folders that Windows XP did. It shouldn't be much of a problem, as no well-behaved app has any business doing that in the first place.

Comment: ... and some big company in the Seattle area has urged people to follow some guidance on that kind of business since they introduced some big product somewhere around 1995.

Comment: Yes, but stubborn developers don't listen to such advice until the OS changes and breaks their dirty code.  Developers are pain motivated. ;>