# What causes significant loss of FP precision when compiling for 64-bit?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, floating-point

Platform: C# using Visual Studio 2013.

I had a Windows Application running on a 64-bit Haswell CPU that was working correctly with ‘Prefer 32-bit’ enabled. I decided to upgrade to ‘Prefer 64-bit’ by de-selecting ‘Prefer 32-bit’ and the Application’s arithmetic changed suddenly to incorrect values. **I LOST 29 BITS OF ARITHMETIC PRECISION** (that’s my estimate of the difference in size of a Double-Precision Floating-Point mantissa and a Single-Precision Floating-Point mantissa). The difference in arithmetic precision here is massive!

**C# code… the test case:**

```
using System;
class lngfltdbl
{
    static void Main()
    {
        long   lng = 2026872;
        float  flt = 0.3F;
        double dbl = lng + flt;
        Console.WriteLine(dbl);
    }
}
```

Expected result (seen when ‘Prefer 32-bit’ is selected):

```
dbl == 2026872.30000001
(PERFECT! CORRECT to 14 decimal places)
```

Obtained Result (seen when ‘Prefer 32-bit’ is de-selected):

```
dbl == 2026872.25
(ERROR!  CORRECT to 7 DECIMAL PLACES ONLY!)
```

Please note: in the past I have been comfortable with implicit casts since 'Prefer 32-bit' always understood how to combine correctly values of differing precision.

Comment: I'd like to point out that your `lng + flt` expression is an invitation for trouble - you shouldn't mix types without explicit conversions (just as the Microsoft answer suggests). I don't think this deserves CAUTION in all capital letters.

Comment: Please rephrase this as a question and answer. You can answer your own question! It's a very interesting and rather strange observation that I feel would be a big contribution to the site.

Comment: @GregRos I feel the question should be “Can a compiler option have functional effects?” and the answer “Yes, obviously. In fact, for a compiler not having functional effects is the exception rather than the rule. For instance, GCC's `-mfpmath=387` [the closest equivalent in GCC to the option under discussion in the question] changes the semantics of the generated code”. If this is not properly documented in C#, it should be a bug report against C#'s documentation, and if it is, this is just a “duh” remark, not a big contribution.

Comment: I'm in the process of making your changes as suggested but unable to add the answer I received from the JIT compiler Team at Microsoft. (I did not want to seperate the answer initially as I did not intend to take any credit for it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Where the error lies:**

With expert assistance, we observed that the assembly code produced with ‘Prefer 32-bit’ deselected is indeed using Single Precision instructions (cvtsi2ss; subss) for computation, then the result is converted to double-precision (cvtss2sd : Convert Scalar Double-Precision FP value to Scalar Double-Precision FP value) and finally the result is stored in a Double Precision variable (movsd). This matches exactly with the symptoms of the detected error and explains the loss of 29 bits of arithmetic precision.

I escalated this to Microsoft and finally got through to someone in the JIT-compiler team. It turned out to be intentional behavior, i.e. if using Double-Precision Floating-Point arithmetic with implicit type casts, the chances are you MUST MODIFY your C# code. Up to now I believed that arithmetic precision relies solely on the length of variables and any explicit/implicit conversions (within the rules of floating point computation defined by IEEE, of course). Furthermore I believed that the choice to compile a working 32-bit application as 64-bit would not change the application behaviour.

I am indebted to Microsoft for sending me the following response…

*The behavior that you are seeing is expected for the particular test case that you provided.  The key here is the expression*

```
lng + flt
```

*The C# compiler generates IL to evaluate this expression.  It doesn’t consider what you are assigning this expression to. Your expression and assignment is relying upon implicit conversion being inserted into your expression. The C# compiler has rules that specify how it will add implicit conversions into expressions when it generates IL for the expression. In this case the C# compiler adds an implicit conversion like this:*

```
((float)lng + flt)
```

*This expression tells the JIT compiler that it should generate code for a single precision floating point ADD operation. So the code generated by the 64-bit target is completely appropriate given the IL that the JIT compiler was given. It was told (by the IL) to compute a 32-bit sized float result and that is what it did as you observed.*

*Here is the IL for this method:*

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       26 (0x1a)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init (int64 V_0,
           float32 V_1,
           float64 V_2)
  IL_0000:  ldc.i4     0x1eed78
  IL_0005:  conv.i8
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldc.r4     0.30000001
  IL_000c:  stloc.1
  IL_000d:  ldloc.0
  IL_000e:  conv.r4    ;; Force the conversion of ‘lng’ into a 32-bit float ‘r4’
  IL_000f:  ldloc.1
  IL_0010:  add
  IL_0011:  conv.r8
  IL_0012:  stloc.2
  IL_0013:  ldloc.2
  IL_0014:  call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(float64)
  IL_0019:  ret
} // end of method lngfltdbl::Main
```

*The question then becomes why did the 32-bit target JIT produce a different (more precise) result?*

*The answer here is that the older 32-bit uses the older x87 style instructions and we have always stated that a JIT compiler may compute intermediate floating point values for expressions at a higher precision.  The 32-bit JIT compiler does in fact compute 32-bit floating expressions at a higher precision.  It does so because that is the natural behavior of the instructions available when using the older x87 style instructions.  We do this because there is a fairly large performance penalty to perform 32-bit floating point operations using the x87 style instructions.  And we document that if you require a 32-bit float result for an intermediate calculation you can add an explicit cast conversion and the JIT is required change the precision to 32-bit float when it sees the explicit cast conversion.*

*For your case you will need to add an explicit cast to 'double' on either of the two operands of the ADD instructions in order for the C# compiler to generate IL that adds two 64-bit floats.*

*Either of these source expressions will compute the result that you want:*

```
((double)lng + flt)
(lng + (double)flt)
```