# What code changes are required to migrate C# to 64-bits?

Tags: c#, .net, 32bit-64bit

I learned that a working 32-bit C# Windows (or Console) Application *may exhibit different functional behavior* when compiled for 64-bits (by deselecting the 'Prefer 32-bit' compiler option in Visual Studio 2013). For more details, see: [What causes significant loss of FP precision when compiling for 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810569/what-causes-significant-loss-of-fp-precision-when-compiling-for-64-bit)

Surprised by the fact that multiple code changes were required (to create code that is **functionally equivalent** when compiled as 32-bit or 64-bit), I ask here the specific question if anyone has come across **other issues** that required changes to existing C# code in order to make it function correctly as a 64-bit application.

*Note: in both cases Windows 7 (or higher) 64-bit is used as the operating system.*

Comment: This heavily depends on the code and the dependencies. A good example is the usage of Int32. Should this be a 32Bit value even in a 64Bit build or not? Unsafe code in general need special attention, especially when working with pointers.

Comment: I disagree ... arithmetic types should be independent of compiling for 32 bits or 64 bits. Arithmetic does not change. Use 'long' (Int64) if your arithmetic requires 64 bit integers ... the JIT-compiler must work it out.

Comment: I didn't talk about arithmetic.

Answer (score 4):

Changes to code, no. .NET code is compiled to MSIL which is platform independent.

The only changes you have to make is using 64-bit referenced assemblies instead of the 32-bit versions (or [native assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0w2664k.aspx) written in C++). This is the case for example with ADO.NET providers that are written for a specific architecture.

Comment: More important: NATIVE Assemblies.

Comment: No. I did not mean that.

Comment: Then how do you explain that a member of the JIT-compiler team at Microsoft confirmed the code changes I need to make? (please refer to the link I supplied)

Comment: I see that as a functional bug. The behavior is the same, the way processed not. In general my answer covers.

Answer (score 0):

No changes because the C# is compiled into Common Intermediate Language (CIL, MSIL is the old name), which is independent of architecture.

Except when you use P/Invoke magic like:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool AbortSystemShutdown(string lpMachineName);
```

On Windows or 3rd party DLL's you might run into trouble when 32-bit DLL's are called from a C# program running in 64-bit mode at runtime.

Comment: Calling `advapi32.dll` works on 64 bit too since the 64 bit version is loaded then. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426286/does-p-invoke-on-64-bit-windows-require-different-signatures-than-on-32-bit

Comment: I assume you mean "No other changes because..."